# Automatically generate scripts for mouse clicks in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, macros, ssms

We can create (update, populate) tables etc by either SQL commands or by simply clicking the options/command with a mouse/keyboard in SQL Server Management Studio (Express) 2008.

Is there a way I can record all the commands that occur when I do it with a mouse?

Are there macro recording features within SSMS?

Are there 3rd party addones to support macro recording in SSMS?

Comment: I am sure there are 3rd party programs that will do this (they don't need to be written specifically for SSMS) - did you search for any?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing built into SSMS to record keystrokes / mouse clicks. [There are plenty of 3rd party programs available, though](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&nord=1&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=keypress%20macro%20recorder).

What you should do is write the commands you want to run using T-SQL or DDL. Those are very easy to save to a file, store in source control, review, run again later, etc.

In newer versions of SSMS, almost all tasks you perform through dialogs has the ability to script out the change you are about to perform (or just generate a script instead of clicking OK):

[image]

**EDIT** for the use case you presented in a comment, where you create a table, add constraints, add some dummy data. Here is what you can do to generate a script that you can use later:

1. Open Object Explorer
2. Right-click your database and choose Tasks > Generate Scripts
3. Click Next, Click Next
4. On the "Choose Script Options" page, scroll down and set "Script Data" to True
5. Click Next
6. Check Tables and click Next
7. Check the table you want and click next
8. Choose whether to script to a file, to the clipboard, or a new query editor window.

You'll end up with something like this:

```
USE [your_database]
GO
/**** set options, object name, script date, etc ****/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[foo](
  bar INT,
  blat INT,
  CONSTRAINT PK_foo PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(bar ASC)
) -- with/on etc.
GO
INSERT [dbo].[foo]([bar],[blat]) VALUES(1,2);
INSERT [dbo].[foo]([bar],[blat]) VALUES(3,4);
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[foo] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [chk_blat]
  CHECK ((blat > bar))
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[foo] CHECK CONSTRAINT [chk_blat]
GO
```

I know this is more steps than you want, but Management Studio's job is not to save every single command you execute and store it somewhere so you can retrieve it later.

Comment: Will the "Script action to file" work on SQL server 2008 ? Or only on 2012 ?

Comment: Should work fine in SQL Server 2008 (I don't now what 2010 is). Did you try it? What dialogs specifically are you trying to record all of your clicks and keystrokes?

Comment: BTW, I did not mean a general keylogger or screenshot software. I meant this - When i perform some actions on a DB, using ONLY my mouse, I want all those actions to appear as commands "somewhere". Then, I can copy those commands and keep them for learning purposes.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything that will watch you click a button in SSMS and then write out the T-SQL that Management Studio executed on your behalf as a result of clicking that button. Think about what you're asking for just for a minute.

Comment: Lets say I create a table. Then I make a few columns. Then I put some constraints on these columns. Then I put test/dummy data into these columns - USING ONLY THE GUI OF MANAGEMENT STUDIO - NO COMMANDS. 
I want my computer to automatically generate the queries associated with the above actions/mouse clicks. Then, I will copy these queries and keep them in a text file.

For example, If i click create table option, then my computer should create a sql query for that and keep it in a text file.

Comment: Well, I am a newbie and I have a lot to learn. BTW, why is this not possible ? If the software generates queries in the background, why are we not allowed to see them ?

Comment: You can see them if you run a trace. The problem is not seeing what queries are sent. The problem is associating a query with a specific mouse click.

Comment: How do i run a trace ? Maybe i can figure out how to use trace to do what i need.

Comment: I really doubt it. The trace is going to be full of stuff you don't want or need, and parsing just the key stuff out of that is going to be a pretty humongous project. But, I mean, [go nuts if you think that's what you really want to do](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/how-to-create-a-server-side-trace-with-sql-profiler/). Personally, I think you'll get much more value out of learning DDL and T-SQL such that you don't need to use the UI.

Comment: Hi ! thanks for the update. Is it just me or could this "feature" (ie record commands for each mouse click/action) be of use to companies/developers ?

Comment: Just for confirmation, this method works for like 95% of what I want in SSMS 2008 ...

Comment: @user1440230 I've been working with SQL Server since the 1990s and I have never heard of another person request this. You can script just about everything you do, but you seem to want a script that will write your trip to the mall in a text file. :-)

Comment: Thanks to all ! I hope they will include this in the future versions :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options that might help.

The SSMS Tools Pack has a query history:
http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Images/Features/QEH1.png

I think this will work as you expect because your interaction with the GUI will translate into T-SQL commands, which should be recorded by this tool.

You can download this here:
http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features

If you start getting familiar with the actual commands you can use SQL Tab Magic, which auto-saves your SSMS query windows for future retrieval:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/entrypage/sqltabmagic